# Python "tagging" wrapper function for class methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, events, event-handling, wrapper

I want to create an event handler for my project. I managed to create a simple one that uses decorators to "subscribe" to an event. However these decorators were not designed for class methods. I can't seem to find a clean way to basically cache the object reference itself so that later on I can call it with `trigger`.

```py
from typing import List, Callable

_subscribed: List[Callable[[str], None]] = []

def subscribe(function: Callable[[str], None]) -> Callable[[str], None]:
    _subscribed.append(function)
    return function

def unsubscribe(function: Callable[[str], None]) -> None:
    del _subscribed[_subscribed.index(function)]

def trigger(msg: str) -> None:
    for function in _subscribed:
        function(msg)

@subscribe
def test(msg: str):
    print(f'From function: {msg}')

class Test:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        pass
    @subscribe
    def on_event(self, msg) -> None:
        print(f'From method: {msg}')

print('Start')
trigger('Hello World')
print('End')
```

The code above should work fine for the function, but not for the method, as `self` must be also passed inside of trigger. My first thought was to create a `Wrapper` class:

```py
class Wrapper:
    def __init__(self, ref: object, func: Callable[[object, str], None]):
        self.ref = ref
        self.func = func
    def __call__(self, *args) -> None:
        self.func(self.ref, *args)
```

and then simply appending an object of this class to the `_subscribed` list. The problem with this is, that I can't find a way to extract the pointer to the `Test` class inside `subscribe`. So my questions are:

1. What is a relative clear way to solve this issue?
2. Is there a way `subscribe` can support both functions AND methods?